# ajax calling same file more number of times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am loading a page using ajax by clicking a button. Inside I have another button on clicking which calls another ajax file. But problem is that if I click first button 2 times then clicking second button calls second file 2 times. If 3 then 3 times and so on.

The code of first call is :

```
        $(document).on("click",".ajaxmenu a, .dropdown a",function(){
                var link_name = $(this).attr('id');
                if(link_name == 'not_this'){return false;}                  
                $('#main-content').html('<div style="margin:10% 0% 0% 35%"><img src="media/loading.gif" ></img></div>');
                var a = this.hash.substr(1);
                $.get( "first.php",{ patient_id : link_name },function( data ) {
                  $('#main-content').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
                });
    });
```

Code for second call is :

```
        $(document).on('click','#cb',function(){
                var test_number = $('#test_number').val();  
                var more_d1 = $('#d1').val();
                var more_d2 = $('#d2').val();
                $.get( "functions/reports_more_content.php",{ tn : test_number, date1 : more_d1, date2 : more_d2} ,function(more_data) {
                    if(more_data == 'asd'){
                        $('#no-more').append("There are no more content to show");
                        $('#cb').remove();
                    }else
                    {
                    $('#next_id').remove(); 
                    $('.more_content').append(more_data);
                    }
                });     
    });
```

Comment: Does the second bit of code get executed after the first AJAX call returns?

Comment: yes.more_data is appearing that no of times

Comment: Write the JS in a separate page and make sure you call it once in the index page. And make ajax calls. And do not include this script in the ajax pages. As it already would exist in the index page.

Comment: which js you are talking about

Comment: The jQuery functions you wrote above. Write then in one .js file.

Comment: problem is solved.thanks AbhishekSaha